# What is the bundle Id of the process that displays security alerts in iOS 11.3?

Tags: xcuitest

I'd like to be able to address this from a XCUITest in order to say something like

`XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "bundle Id").alerts.matching(Foo)`

I already know about `addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: description)`,
but it seems that we might need to wait for the alert to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Springboard app, therefore its Bundle ID is `com.apple.springboard`.

You have it in your logs when you run your tests. This is excerpt from my test logs:

```
t =    31.89s Tap "Location service" Switch
t =    31.89s     Wait for com.mytestapp to idle
t =    31.95s     Find the "Location service" Switch
t =    32.01s         Wait for com.apple.springboard to idle
t =    32.05s     Synthesize event
t =    32.16s     Wait for com.mytestapp to idle
```